# Why am I getting the error No accessible photos found for Flickr?

Tags: drupal, flickr

I am using the drupal module: flickr (https://drupal.org/project/flickr)

When I go to mysite/flickr/uid/ I get the error message "No accessible photos found for Flickr (my flicker id)".

When I output the url and try to go to that page, I get a page not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to change 
define('FLICKR_REST_ENDPOINT', 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/');
to
define('FLICKR_REST_ENDPOINT', 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/');